# Автоматическое тестирование всех классов, реализующих интерфейс

Tags: c#, nunit

я делаю один проект на C#, и в нём есть некий интерфейс и несколько его наследников.

Для тестирования используется NUnit.

Вопрос, можно ли написать тесты непосредственно к интерфейсу, чтобы каждый его наследник проходил эти тесты? И я мог увидеть, объекты какого класса не прошли тесты.

Спасибо.

Comment: Покажите код упрощённо, что именно хотите протестировать.

Comment: Вообще, да, нечто такое можно сделать. Параметризованные тесты, в которые подаются на вход все наследники, которые получаются рефлексией из сборки (хотя проще вручную их добавить).

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Замучаетесь с параметрами конструкторов. Да и смысла мало в этом. Если все наследники ведут себя одинаково - то смысла нет в нескольких имплементациях. Если они ведут себя немного по другому - то надо пилить отдельные тесты для каждого

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, tym32167.